# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 261727: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, unicode, bigdata

I appreciate your help.
My question is method about sorting big data(csv) with 3rd column.
It operates normally up to 1 million lines input data, but for inputs longer than that, the error message below appears.
I think this error is related with big size input data not input format.
I searched in google, but i didn't solve this problem.
Help me please. thanks.

`code`

```
#!/bin/python   
#aaa.py   
import os   
import csv   
import sys   
import pandas as pd   

def main(argv):
    f=open(argv[1],"r")
    df=pd.read_csv(f, encoding ='cp949')
    sorted_df=df.sort_values(by='c')
    sorted_df.to_csv("output_sorted.csv")
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)

[input data]  
a,b,c  
abc,2022-12-23 10:00:35,2022-12-23 22:00:35  
def,2016-06-01 10:46:32,2016-06-01 16:46:32  
ghi,2018-03-27 13:56:52,2018-03-27 19:56:52  
jkl,2020-09-30 15:16:49,2020-09-30 20:06:37  
...  
...

[Error message]  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/aaa.py", line 33, in <module>  
    main(sys.argv)  
  File "/home/aaa.py", line 12, in main  
    df=pd.read_csv(f, encoding ='cp949')  
  File "/home/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv  
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)  
  File "/home/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 460, in _read  
    data = parser.read(nrows)  
  File "/home/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1198, in read  
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)  
  File "/home/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2157, in read  
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)  
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read  
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory  
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 918, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows  
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 905, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows  
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2034, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 261727: invalid start byte  

def,2016-06-01 10:46:32,2016-06-01 16:46:32  
ghi,2018-03-27 13:56:52,2018-03-27 19:56:52  
jkl,2020-09-30 15:16:49,2020-09-30 20:06:37  
abc,2022-12-23 10:00:35,2022-12-23 22:00:35  
... ...
```

Comment: Is your data really in cp949 encoding? You can try and recode it to utf8 with an external tool such as iconv.

Comment: thnank you. I tried to encode utf8, but same error message.. and except encoding in code, happened to same error message..

Comment: What exact command did you use to recode to utf'8_

Comment: The error you're seeing has nothing to do with the data size. You don't get as far as trying to sort. You may have confused matters by opening the file in one encoding and then telling pandas to use another. Just give the filename to read_csv. Do you know for certain what the encoding for your input file is?

Comment: yes. i know about encoding format.
`[root@aaa]# ss2 incoding_format.py inputdata.csv 
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}


[root@aaa]# more incoding_format.py 
import chardet

with open('inputdata.csv', 'rb') as rawdata:
        result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(13941237))


        # check what the character encoding might be
        print(result)
`